# Functions defined on open intervals

Tags: real-analysis

This is an Exercise from David Brannan Book "A First Course in Mathematical Analysis " .Let $f$ be defined on an open interval $I$, $c \in I$. Prove that if $f$ is continuous at $c$ and $f(c) \neq 0$ , then there is an open interval $J \subset I$ such that , $c \in J$ and $f(x)\neq 0$ , $\forall x \in J$ . I should add that the only definition of continuity I have to work with at this point in the text is this : A function $f$ defined on a set $S$ in Reals that contains a point $c$ is continuous at $c$ if : for each sequence $\{x(n)\}$ in $S$ , such that $x(n)$ tends to $c$ , $f(x(n))$ tends to $f(c)$..... Any help on this problem is much appreciated...

Answer (score 0):

**HINT**: The missing piece of information is the definition of "tends to", which in your book will have been a delta-epsilon definition.  If you choose $\epsilon$ to be less than $|f(e)|$ you get a $\delta$ that can then be used (use $\delta/2)$ as the distance from $e$ defining the new open interval.

Comment: Thanks very much Mark for your quick answer , but at this point (Chapter 4) I have only a sequence definition of continuity not epsilon delta...Of course at this point I do have an epsilon and N definition of convergence......

Answer (score 0):

Suppose that there is no such interval $J$. Then every open interval $J \subset I$ contains a point $x$ such that $f(x) = 0$. Since $I$ is open and contains $c$, the interval $J_n = (c - 1/n, c + 1/n)$ will be contained in $I$ for all sufficiently large $n$, and there is a point $x_n \in J_n$ such that $f(x_n) = 0$. Since $f$ is continuous at $c$ and $x_n \to c$,
$$\lim_{n \to \infty}f(x_n) = f\left(\lim_{n \to \infty}x_n \right) = f(c) \neq 0$$
But this is a contradiction, since $f(x_n) = 0$ for all sufficiently large $n$.